# Files Don't Appear on Desktop?

Tags: desktop, files, app-shortcuts

When I place a file in the Desktop folder it dosen't appear on my screens desktop?

Answer (score 4):

There is not a desktop folder in elementary OS, you can't put icons or files in the desktop, all the icons go to the dock bar and the files to your home folder

Comment: Just an FYI, once a question has been marked as a duplicate you don't generally want to be posting answers there. If this is needed, it should go on the original question.